# fdpf remote images not working

Tags: php, fpdf

hello friends i am using **FPDF PHP** library to generate PDF. but when i use image method and image source as a remote image it doesn't shows up anything. what am i doing wrong please help ..
for example

```
 <?
 $this->pdf->Image('http://all-pic.com/wp-content/uploads/fefad025f1bc8db580dcc7ce7a4b2f07.jpg',$this->pdf->GetX(),$this->pdf->GetY(),50,50);
?>
```

however this works fine

```
<?
 $this->pdf->Image('localimage.jpg',$this->pdf->GetX(),$this->pdf->GetY(),50,50);
?>
```

i have allow_url_fopen installed and on in my php settings.

Comment: I doubt the fpdf library implements a network transparent `Image()` method. Where did you get that idea from?

Answer (score 0):

Copy the remote image to your server and then use the local image in FPDF:

```
<?php
copy('http://example.com/remoteimage.jpg', '/tmp/localimage.jpg');

$this->pdf->Image('/tmp/localimage.jpg',$this->pdf->GetX(),$this->pdf->GetY(),50,50);
?>
```